# Get values from custom tag of a textbox(autocomplete) and push into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a one text-box(autocomplete) on page with id main_text,whose value changes dynamically.

```
    '<'my_custom_tag'>'name1|name2|address|country|provison'<'/my_custom_tag'>'
```

In above tag **please do not consider any single quote**, for display purpose i have mentioned it over here,other wise it was only displaying **name1|name2|address|country|provison**.

I want to get all the value between tags and push it into an array. I have tried using .result method of jquery but it was showing an error stating **$(...).result not found**

```
   $("#main_text").result(function(event,data,formatted){}
```

Any alternative approach to achieve the same, we need to **.split** the value from | so i can get individual values ,after that i will set those values into another text-box.

```
   $("my_name1").val(my_array[0]);
   $("my_name2").val(my_array[1]);
   $("my_address").val(my_array[2]);
   $("my_country").val(my_array[3]);
   $("my_provison").val(my_array[4]);
```

Also, if you check this link jqueryui.com/autocomplete it states .autocomplete is not a function in DOM

Comment: What is exactly the question? How to access the content of the tag? How to split into words? Something other?

Comment: access the content of tag,split into words and set into other text-box.

Comment: How does @mentallurg's answer not work for you? Like if the text in your tag is `'||||'` you don't want to get empty strings in your array?

Comment: Its when you start typing something into box and when you move to another field it should get those value(split + set value into totherbox),but below method does not do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
values = $("my_custom_tag").text().split("|");
```

Comment: It's an autocomplete this will not work in that case. i get the blank values

Comment: Your current description "I have a ...  text-box ... whose value is" contradicts with "autocomplete". Describe your case correctly.

Comment: It is still not clear why you cannot use what I have suggested. Do you use this element to represent a value of "autocomplete"? Thne this will work. Or may be you have another element that is responsible for autocomplete and you are jst extracting the text from the wrong element? Or may be the element is correct, but you are accessing it at the wrong moment, when it is empty yet? If the latter, then create an event listener and extract value each time after your input text changes, e.g. after each changed letter.

Comment: can you guide why  .result(function(event,data,formatted){} gives me an error : $(...).result is not a function
Jquery version : 3.0.0 
jquery UI : 1.12
It was working previously but after up-gradation to 3.0.0 it stopped working.

Comment: Also, if you check this link https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ it states .autocomplete is not a function in DOM

Comment: In the older versions there was $(...).autocomplete(...).result(function(){...}). Do you mean that? See examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718373/replacement-of-bind-in-jquery.