# jQuery - retrieve value of autocomplete element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to retrieve the value of autocomplete textbox. I tried to use the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#my_id').bind('result',function(){});
```

Any suggestions will be helpful. I don't want to use .text() as it does not satisfies my requirements. Some thing similar to 'result' will be excellent.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what your question is. Please clearly state the problem you're facing and what the expected result is. Incidentally, `.on()` superceded `.bind()` in JQuery some time ago.

Comment: `on()` is the replacement. I assume this is a third-party plugin which is creating a `result` event that you're attempting to hook to?

Comment: we are using jquery-ui but we have read somewhere to get the data from autocomplete we have to use .bind('result') and no event was working.i have tried .on() as well but the result is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options.

A) Use event handler **select** of **autocomplete**:

```
$("#my_id").autocomplete({..., select: function(event, ui){...}});
```

B) Use event handler **autocompleteselect**:

```
$("#my_id").on("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui){...}});
```

In the debugger you can see, that the event in both cases has the same type `autocompleteselect`. The both approaches are equivalent. You may choose A, if you prefer to keep all the related code together, within a single block. You may choose B, if you prefer strong separation of filling of the autocompletion list from the reaction on the selection.

**Example for A:**

Type 'a' or 'j' in the input field to see how it works.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var availableItems = [
        "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Groovy", "Java", "JavaScript", "Python", "Scala"
      ];
      $("#my_items").autocomplete({
        source: availableItems,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          alert(
            "input: " + event.target.value + "\n" +
            "label: " + ui.item.label + "\n" +
            "value: " + ui.item.value);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="my_items">Items: </label>
    <input id="my_items">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**Example for B:**

Type 'a' or 'j' in the input field to see how it works.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var availableItems = [
        "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Groovy", "Java", "JavaScript", "Python", "Scala"
      ];
      $("#my_items").autocomplete({
        source: availableItems
      });

      $("#my_items").on("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
          alert(
            "input: " + event.target.value + "\n" +
            "label: " + ui.item.label + "\n" +
            "value: " + ui.item.value);
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="my_items">Items: </label>
    <input id="my_items">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```